# Almost Equilaterial Heronian Triangles

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, sequence

An *Almost Equilateral Heronian Triangle* is a triangle with integer lengths of the form `n-1`, `n`, and `n+1` and also has integer area. The first few are:

```
 3,  4,  5 ->    6
13, 14, 15 ->   84
51, 52, 53 -> 1170
```

**Quest**: Generate the shortest program that outputs the `n`th such triple. (Hint: this is a known sequence).

Winner will be selected on May 2, 2014.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is equivalent to one of the more widely studied Pell equations.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes. This is a fairly simple task but I don't see any problem with the question. But I have to say (as a left handed person) that the restriction is one of the weirdest and easiest to comply with I have ever seen.

Comment: @steveverrill, although I didn't downvote I did choose not to upvote because of the pointless restriction. I suspect that the close votes are also because of the restriction: I bet that less than 10% of the world's population use the same keyboard layout as Kyle.

Comment: I would upvote without the restriction.

Comment: @TheDoctor: Restriction removed. I had thought that it would make it interesting, but given the comments above it seems this is not the case.

Comment: i liked the restriction @KyleKanos, even though left-handed people disgust me

Comment: @ardnew Of all the places, this is one of the least likely I would expect such handist comments :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### APL, <strike>15</strike> 14 charaters

```
0 1 2+⌊⎕*⍨2+√3
```

Same approach as [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)'s solution but uses floor instead of the correction term.

Thank you to [algorithmshark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5138/algorithmshark) for pointing out that the commute operator saves one char.

Comment: `(⍳3)` saves a char over `0 1 2`, and I'm pretty sure you can use Commute to make it `⎕*⍨2+√3` and save another.

Comment: @algorithmshark Thank you for those ideas. Unfortunately `⍳3` yields `1 2 3` and thus is one char longer.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>26, 22, 16</s> 18 chars

```
{0,1,2}+⌊(2+√3)^n⌋
```

Comment: A bit too much golfing: it won't work in the current form (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={0%2C1%2C2}%2B%E2%8C%8A2%2B%E2%88%9A3%E2%8C%8B^2)).

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (<strike>24</strike> 21 chars)

```
2 4@~{.4*@-}*;.(\.)]p
```

Takes input on stdin, gives output to stdout in the form

```
[3 4 5]
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyczJwoKMiA0QH57LjQqQC19KjsuKFwuKV1wCg%3D%3D)

Note that I've assumed that the 0th element of the sequence is `[1 2 3]` (with area 0), which I think is consistent with [OEIS A003500](http://oeis.org/A003500).

With thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard) for a 3-char saving.

Comment: Using `(.).)]` is two chars shorter. Moreover, if you start with `2 4` you can replace `\;` with `;` and save an additional one.

Comment: @Howard, I originally had `2 4` and treated `[3 4 5]` as the 0th element, so I'm embarrassed not to have spotted that alternative way to exploit the offset. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU dc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/), <strike>30</strike> 19 bytes

```
9k3v2+?^0k1/p1+p1+p
```

This uses the same trick as [@Howard's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26118/11259) so only one term has to be calculated.  Takes input for n from stdin.

Output:

```
$ dc -e '9k3v2+?^0k1/p1+p1+p' <<< 1
3
4
5
$ dc -e '9k3v2+?^0k1/p1+p1+p' <<< 2
13
14
15
$ dc -e '9k3v2+?^0k1/p1+p1+p' <<< 3
51
52
53
$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 77

Quite a verbose implementation in Python

```
[(a-1,a,a+1)for a in(int((2+3**.5)**t+(2-3**.5)**t+.1)for t in range(N))][-1]
```

Comment: Are we supposed to replace `N` with a value? Your program doesn't ask for any input.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 83 characters

```
f=lambda t:4*f(t-1)-f(t-2)if t>2 else(4,14)[t-1];n=f(int(input()));print(n-1,n,n+1)
```

This uses a recursive solution, taking advantage of the fact that (quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle#Almost-equilateral_Heronian_triangles)):

> Subsequent values of n can be found by multiplying the previous value by 4, then subtracting the value prior to that one (52 = 4 × 14 − 4, 194 = 4 × 52 − 14, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) - 52 Characters

```
f=x=>x?--x?4*f(x)-f(x-1):4:2
g=x=>[a=f(x)-1,a+1,a+2]
```

Defines a recursive function `f` which returns the n<sup>th</sup> term and a function `g` which returns an array containing the corresponding triple.

## JavaScript - 41 Characters

```
for(a=2,b=4;--x;)b=-a+4*(a=b);[a-1,a,a+1]
```

Expects the term to be calculated to be stored in the global variable `x` and outputs the triple to the console.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
3,3mq))ri#if+p
```

The first version of CJam is 10 days older than this challenge, but I don't know if all of the features I'm using have been present back then. The challenge is officially closed anyway though, so...

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=3%2C3mq))ri%23if%2Bp&input=3)

### Explanation

```
3mq            e# Push √3.
   ))          e# Increment twice.
     ri        e# Read input and convert to integer.
       #       e# Raise 2+√3 to that power.
        i      e# Convert to integer, truncating the result.
         3,    e# Push [0 1 2]
           f+  e# Add the previous number to each of these.
             p e# Pretty-print the result.
```